# How to expand the accordion item and highlight successful native input validation inside the collapsed accordion item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to trigger native form input built in validation when accordion is collapsed and validation is successful(in other words input value is empty).
Inputs inside the accordion items are set  with `required` attribute.
This means, that if one of the inputs are empty and user clicks the `submit button`, will trigger the validation error:  `Please fill in this field`.

So far so good.

Let's see if it works when accordion items are collapsed.

 No, it doesn't. It just does nothing.

Why?
It seems not to trigger the validation if corresponding html element has `visibility: hidden` or maybe `display: none`. 
I'm trying to find a workaround, so that when accordion item is collapsed, input value is empty and user clicks submit button it expands accordion item and highlighs the validation message, but couldn't find a solution so far.
Here is [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-validation-j6zixv?file=/index.js:532-540) and code below.

```
import React, { useState, StrictMode } from "react";
import { Accordion, AccordionItem } from "@carbon/react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

const App = () => {
  const [text1, setText1] = useState("");
  const [text2, setText2] = useState("");
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);

  const toggleHandle = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("text1", text1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={toggleHandle}>{toggle ? "collapse" : "expand"}</button>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Accordion>
          <AccordionItem title="Title 1" open={toggle}>
            <input
              required
              value={text1}
              onChange={(e) => setText1(e.target.value)}
            />
          </AccordionItem>
          <AccordionItem open={toggle} title="Title 2">
            <input
              required
              value={text2}
              onChange={(e) => setText2(e.target.value)}
            />
          </AccordionItem>
        </Accordion>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Any help will be appreciated

**UPDATE** 
I found a workaround adding custom error and invoking it in `setTimeOut`.
But I am not sure that this is the best solution.
Rather than it works only for one input, but in my case there are more inputs.
So my question is, if i should define for each of them like i did for the first accrodion input or there is a better solution?
Here is [the updated link](https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-validation-forked-49zhrf?file=/index.js)

Comment: Hey, take a look to this article. It’s something related https://www.falldowngoboone.com/blog/native-form-validation-with-javascript/

Comment: @Greg I tried to find a solution, but couldn't find a workaround. 
Could you provide an example, please?